# Match duplicate images by content and rename them (to the name of the duplicate)

Tags: images, batch-rename, duplicate

I have 2 folders with over 5.000 photos each:

- **Folder 1:** the original files in good quality but with human readable names (e.g. `saigon_motorcycle_traffic.jpg`)
- **Folder 2:** the same files in really bad quality (450px width) but with clean ids that match to a database (e.g. `562634.jpg`).

The goal is to match the highres pictures to the database IDs.

**My question:** What would be the fastest way to rename the highres version `saigon_motorcycle_traffic.jpg` to its lowres counterpart `562634.jpg`?

---

*I have tried a bunch of software (e.g. [Duplicate photo cleaner](https://www.duplicatephotocleaner.com/), [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page), XnView, DupliFinder, ...), they all found the duplicates but none of them offered a proper way for this kind of renaiming or a suitable export function.*

*Edit: I have not tried any scripts (as noted in the comments) as I know of none and didn't find any. If you know anything please let me know.*

*Some things won't work: matching the image dimensions will not work (most images have the same dimensions), matching the creation date won't work (that's all messed up) and doing it by hand won't work since I want to keep my mental health ;-)*

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi David, after reading some other questions (and now after checking your link) I decided that it's a valid question for SU. I still think that, but yes I am a newbie. That being said: I am not looking for someone to write a script for me, but any hint towards an algorithm or a software is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a PHP routine (I'll not post the full code as it's a really unclean solution) that did the trick.

Using [phasher](https://github.com/kennethrapp/phasher) I was able to iterate over all image files and find the suspected(!) duplicates: every image is transformed to a small hash (based on a 8x8 version of the image). These hashes can then be compared.

2 things to keep in mind:

- since it's a nested loop it's important to get all the hashes first and cache them before doing the actual comparision. Otherwise it will take forever.
- the approach does NOT give perfect results. I had a small error rate in the first run. So there was still some error checking to be done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've had some frustrating experiences with photo duplicate cleaning software. Have you considered using a [duplicate photos fixer](https://www.duplicatephotosfixer.com/) that not only finds duplicates, but also offers features for renaming and exporting your photos? These types of tools can be more comprehensive and provide a better overall experience. You may want to research and try a few different options to find the best one for your needs.